# use grpc and pyspark on kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, microservices, grpc

hi i need help on how to use spark and kubernetes together. In my team they want to make an application that allows a client to send a request to a server running on kubernetes to get some data. The server once it gets the request forwards it to a spark cluster on kubernetes to get the data and forward it to the client.
I give an example for better understanding:
Client A sends a request to server B. Server B forwards the request to a spark cluster C. C gets the data from the source requested by A, generates a dataframe that it passes to B, and B sends the dataframes to the client in response.
Is it possible to implement this architecture ?

I have seen that there is a spark operator on kubernetes but I do not quite understand how to make my server interact with the clusters. I had thought of a solution similar to how it is done in jupyter cells (spark interactive mode) but I don't know if it is a feasible solution. Sorry for all these questions but I am not very familiar yet with spark and kubernetes.

Comment: Perhaps [Spark Connect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-connect-overview.html) will work out for you?